# Active nav item with custom html elements

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing, web-component

I'm building a nav component using html custom elements like so:

**HTML**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<template>
<style>
    ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        gap: 20px;
    }
    a {
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .active {
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/page-one.html">Nav item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page-two.html">Nav item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page-three.html">Nav item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
class AppNavBar extends HTMLElement { 
 constructor() { 
  super();
  this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  const template = document.querySelector('template');
  this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
 }
}
window.customElements.define("app-navbar", AppNavBar)
```

And now I need to pass the active class onto the respective nav item. For example when click on `<a href="/page-two.html">Nav item 2</a>` I want that item to get the class .active and so on.

**Update**

Something like:

page-one.html

`<app-navbar page-one-nav-item="active"></app-navbar>`

page-two.html

`<app-navbar page-two-nav-item="active"></app-navbar>`

page-three.html

`<app-navbar page-three-nav-item="active"></app-navbar>`

Is this possible to achieve with html custom elements?

Thank you.

Comment: This code will navigate to another HTML page, what is the point of a class?

Comment: When landing on another page I want the respective nav item to get activated.

Comment: I've updated my question. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: That requires javascript reading the url,setting the class, nothing related to webcomponents

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a Web Component, wrap the `<a>` in a Web Component:

`<nav-a href="/page-one.html">Nav item 1</nav-a>`

```js
console.log(location);
customElements.define("nav-a", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(() => { // make sure innerHTML is parsed
      let href = this.getAttribute("href");
      let klass = (location.href.includes(href)) ? "active" : "";
      this.innerHTML = `<a class="${klass}" href="${href}">${this.innerHTML}</a>`;
    });
  }
});
```